# How to enable fingerprint for screen unlocking and PolicyKit authentiation in Kubuntu 22.10?

Tags: kubuntu, fingerprint-reader, 22.10, policykit

I registered 2 fingerprints, but they don't seem to show up or work.

Here's my fingerprint reader according to `lsusb` of my 4th generation ThinkPad X1 Yoga:

```
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass        16 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x06cb Synaptics, Inc.
  idProduct          0x00bd Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 1 2d92cfb68025
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/fprint/$USER/
total 0
drwx------ 1 root root 24 Jan 30 22:52 synaptics
```

```
$ journalctl -u fprintd.service
Jan 30 22:52:21 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jan 30 22:52:22 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Jan 30 22:52:25 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th fprintd[104093]: Authorization denied to :1.1537 to call method 'Release' for device 'Synaptics Sensors': Device was not claimed before use
Jan 30 22:53:49 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th fprintd[104093]: Authorization denied to :1.1537 to call method 'EnrollStop' for device 'Synaptics Sensors': Device was not claimed before use
Jan 30 22:53:49 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th fprintd[104093]: Authorization denied to :1.1537 to call method 'Release' for device 'Synaptics Sensors': Device was not claimed before use
Jan 30 22:54:19 Kuroneko-ThinkPadX1Yoga4th systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Comment: I think this could be a good question, but people will most likely want to know more such as your fingerprint reader you are using.  Usually a simple "lsusb" can get you close to that information.

Comment: @Goddard I added it.

Comment: Do you see anything in /var/lib/fprint/$USER/ ?

Also it looks like your device is supported so that is good.  https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html

Comment: Also add the log messages.  journalctl -u fprintd.service

Comment: Added both outputs